# Does it consider republishing(not the whole content) news with source as copyright?

Tags: seo, google

> Eg: According to BBC, China has said that it has successfully landed a
>   robotic spacecraft on the far side of the Moon, the first ever such
>   landing. The more information about this was published on CNN and they
>   clearly mentioned that it is..................

Above type of content consider as copyright or illegal?

Comment: You've asked about copying content from other sources a number of times now - the answer isn't going to change based on whether you copy all or part of it:  Anything that appears on a website is considered copyrighted. If it's not licensed under the Creative Commons attribution license, then you need permission by the author to reproduce it.

Comment: Can't this (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/119996/does-it-consider-republishingnot-the-whole-content-news-with-source-as-copyrig?noredirect=1#comment160689_119996) be a bug of the site? Because I didn't post twice. And I can see the asked time of both time is 5:22... Do you have access to check ful time? So you can check the seconds also.

Comment: I haven't seen that before, perhaps you clicked twice on the submit button quickly... It doesn't really matter in any case - the system will notify us if there's a duplicate post and we'll just delete it (like I did).